# c++ client with php monitoring server

Tags: php, c++

I'm trying to make a simple project. first i will make a simple c++ client, it function is generate a random string and ID. Then if I run the c++ client, and if I look in the php server, it will just show this ID is online, then the php server will send request to c++ client to get the random string, then the c++ will send it to the php. I do have some basic knowledge in c++ and php, but I don't know how to do this kind of stuff. I hope someone can guide me to the correct learning path, or just tell me what should I learned to accomplish this simple project. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Start with learning `sockets` ([here for example](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/)), such you can build a `c++` client \ server.

`PHP` gets requests by `GET` and `POST` methods, i suppose you know it.

It's all you need.